# Boto S3 logging bucket delete

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I have a set of buckets that have logging enabled and they're sending all their logs to a single bucket.  If I delete the logging bucket, do I have to go and disable logging on all the buckets?  Will things error later on if I don't or is boto smart enough to realize the logging bucket is gone and fail quietly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a question of whether boto is smart enough or not.  Once the logging is configured via boto (or any other client) it's really up to the S3 service to handle it.  I think it would be good practice to remove the logging configuration from the buckets if logging bucket has been deleted but even if you don't, S3 will simply not write the logs.